# How to get Meteor real time update between browser and mobile simulator?

Tags: meteor

I created default scaffolding app in Meteor and after installing mobile platform I ran it in simulator (both Android and iOS).  I also opened a browser to view the app (localhost:3000). When pressing Click Me button I do not see any updates in either of the simulator running this app.

Clicking button on browser page shows count increase on browser and this increased count is not reflected on simulator. See screenshot below.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean: When clicking nothing happens on neither screen (the counter doesn't change anywhere), or that the changes are not perpetuated on the other screen?

Comment: Count increase is not synched / reflected in simulator page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor 'click me' application stores the count of the clicks in the session. Your browser and the mobile simulator have different sessions. You need to store the count in the database if you want to see it in the simulator too.

Comment: This made sense.  I just tried with example todos app and yes they are synched properly.